Repeated SSH Passphrase Prompts During Git Push with LFS-enabled Repository
I'm experiencing repeated prompts for my SSH passphrase when performing a git push in a repository that uses Git LFS. This repository is a backup tracking a large amount of work, and the issue occurs consistently.
Symptoms:

When I attempt to git push, I am repeatedly prompted to re-enter my SSH passphrase.
The issue resolves temporarily when I add my SSH key to the SSH agent using ssh-add.

What I've Tried:

SSH Key Management: Added my SSH key to the SSH agent using ssh-add, which temporarily resolves the issue.
LFS Consideration: Although my repository uses Git LFS, I don't believe the issue is directly related to LFS, as the repeated passphrase prompts occur before reaching the LFS file upload stage.
SSH Configuration: Checked my SSH configuration to ensure it seems standard, and other repositories are working fine without this issue.

Environment

OS: macOS Sonoma 14.5
Git Version: 2.39.3 (Apple Git-146)
LFS: 3.4.0
SSH: OpenSSH 9.6
Client: GitHub

Additional Information:

This issue doesn't occur with smaller repositories or those not using Git LFS.
My SSH key is correctly configured and works with other repositories.

Since this is happening on my machine, it’s not easily reproducible per say. Given this context, I am looking for any advice or troubleshooting steps to resolve this issue and willing to provide additional information if necessary. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Which OS, and which Git client?

@JimRedmond I have made the appropriate edits.

Have the exact same issue on NixOS.
